# How to find the source process of DNS traffic?

Tags: dns, tcpdump, netstat, rhel6

Every day at a specific time there is a denial DNS traffic in tcpdump for this DNS traffic.

```
03:10:01.188267 IP hostname.21355 > h.root-servers.net.domain: 52619% [1au] NS? . (28)
03:10:01.188294 IP hostname.19992 > e.root-servers.net.domain: 33364% [1au] NS? . (28)
03:10:01.564808 IP hostname.27167 > e.root-servers.net.domain: 17614% [1au] NS? . (28)
03:10:01.564845 IP hostname.47993 > h.root-servers.net.domain: 39462% [1au] NS? . (28)
03:10:01.941076 IP hostname.33760 > j.root-servers.net.domain: 56169% [1au] NS? . (28)
03:10:01.941446 IP hostname.7920 > h.root-servers.net.domain: 54000% [1au] NS? . (28)
03:10:02.317699 IP hostname.4292 > j.root-servers.net.domain: 11824% [1au] NS? . (28)
03:10:02.694087 IP hostname.55797 > c.root-servers.net.domain: 20468% [1au] NS? . (28)
03:10:02.694383 IP hostname.29552 > h.root-servers.net.domain: 62991% [1au] NS? . (28)
03:10:03.070598 IP hostname.42961 > c.root-servers.net.domain: 47966% [1au] NS? . (28)
03:10:03.447014 IP hostname.23176 > d.root-servers.net.domain: 61501% [1au] NS? . (28)
03:10:03.447366 IP hostname.14098 > b-2016.b.root-servers.net.domain: 24736% [1au] NS? . (28)
```

But we could not find the source process even by scheduling continuous `netstat -tulpne` in a while loop without sleep. The connection is failing immediately and hence not captured in `netstat` I suppose. Even the PID is active only for a fraction of seconds.

Is there any way of finding the source process that initiates this connection?

Comment: There is just libs package for bind and unbound in the server and both the services are inactive.

[root@hostname ~]# rpm -qa | egrep -i "unbound|bind"
unbound-libs-1.4.20-29.el6_10.1.x86_64
bind-libs-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.8.x86_64
bind-utils-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.8.x86_64
PackageKit-device-rebind-0.5.8-26.el6.x86_64
rpcbind-0.2.0-16.el6.x86_64
samba-winbind-3.6.23-53.el6_10.x86_64
samba-winbind-clients-3.6.23-53.el6_10.x86_64
ypbind-1.20.4-33.el6.x86_64

Anyhow I have uninstalled unbound-libs, will monitor and revert back.

Comment: "denial DNS traffic"? Why do you deny this traffic? What exactly is the problem you are chasing because those queries are certainly not the source of your problems. Also your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: As part of security policy, internet traffic is blocked in firewall. These DNS traffic is denied at firewall end.

Comment: How do you expect public DNS resolution to work then?

Comment: We have an internal DNS server and the server is pointing to it. Public DNS resolution is not required.

Comment: Then you need to have a local root zonefile not pointing at public root nameservers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These queries are called priming queries. They are used by DNS resolvers to update the list and IP addresses of the DNS root servers. You likely have a DNS server, such as BIND or Unbound, running which uses these queries to keep the cache updated.

Comment: There is just libs package for bind and unbound in the server and both the services are inactive.

[root@hostname ~]# rpm -qa | egrep -i "unbound|bind"
unbound-libs-1.4.20-29.el6_10.1.x86_64
bind-libs-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.8.x86_64
bind-utils-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.8.x86_64
PackageKit-device-rebind-0.5.8-26.el6.x86_64
rpcbind-0.2.0-16.el6.x86_64
samba-winbind-3.6.23-53.el6_10.x86_64
samba-winbind-clients-3.6.23-53.el6_10.x86_64
ypbind-1.20.4-33.el6.x86_64

Anyhow I have uninstalled unbound-libs, will monitor and revert back.

Comment: Unbound service was not running but still unbound-libs was the cause of these DNS queries. Thanks for the advice.